# Make rotated text take entire height of parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Hey i was just messing with some css transforms and i can't make this happen,

https://codepen.io/simobm/pen/YvoOMO

Im using Bootstrap 4 and so i make 2 columns , on the left there is an image and on the right some text, now i want the text to to be vertical and centered so i use :

```
transform:rotate(90deg)
```

on the text and :

```
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
```

On  the column itself . The problem as you can see is that on mobile, the text breaks to 2 lines and 3 lines consecutively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a handy `text-nowrap` class that you can apply that will stop the text from becoming multiple lines.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-9 ">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521818372696-23e67aff37a5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=b42f31aba73642725afa0a222d211542" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <p class="rotate text-nowrap">Azurmendi by ENEKO ATXA</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/tentacular261/pen/aKgxJm)

Without handling text resizing, this can have some potentially undesirable effects on mobile.

#### Useful Links

- [Bootstrap `text-nowrap` Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow)